# How to show only one world map in Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to learn Google Map from Javascript API. When trying to plot the LatLng in Map, it is showing multiple world maps infinitely.

How can I avoid this to show only one map?

[image: Google Map Showing Infinite times]

Comment: adjust zoom level

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code that shows the example of displaying a Map. (Make 
sure to update the key in `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**********"></script>`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Google Map</h1>

<div id="map" style="width:300px;height:300px></div>

<br>
<script>
function myMap() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.1676870, -86.5354682),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**************"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
}
```

Notice the `zoom` field.  If you don't have that, add it and set it to something like 2.  If you do have it just keep increasing it by 1 until you're happy with it.